# ActiveAdmin Collection action on filtered data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a custom collection action on the index page, and I want to access the filtered data inside that action. How can I do this? Can I get the collection itself? or maybe the filter params?

```
  collection_action :do_something do
    # call some async process
    redirect_to :action => :index, :notice => "started working!"
  end

  action_item :only => :index do
    link_to('DO WORK', do_something_admin_game_stats_path)
  end
```

Comment: What does your custom action code look like?

Comment: added a code sample @JoshKovach

Comment: Would it make more sense to use a `batch_action` here? That way you can use the select columns on the currently scoped items...

Comment: @JoshKovach I'd rather not force the user to make this extra step + when there are multiple pages, the 'select all' checkbox only selects the first page and I want to run an action on the entire set of filtered data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should pass the `scope` and `filter` params as options on your `link_to` action, and then use `scoped_collection` within your `collection_action`.

```
link_to "DO WORK", do_something_admin_game_stats_path(param.slice(:scope, :filter))
```

I'm not sure if filter is the correct param key, but the principle should be the same. If for some reason you can't access `params` in the action link, try `controller.params` or if you're really desperate `controller.send(:params)`. Off the top of my head I'm not sure if the params are publicly available in views off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

The second option is to send these params inside `post` request

```r
  collection_action :do_something do
    resource_class.ransack(params[:q]).result # returns filtered records 
    redirect_to :action => :index, :notice => "started working!"
  end

  action_item :only => :index do
    button_to 'DO WORK', do_something_admin_game_stats_path, method: :post, params: params.slice(:q)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the session to pass the filtered data to the collection_action itself.

```
collection_action :do_something do
   # call some async process
   filtered_data = session[:filtered_data]
   redirect_to :action => :index, :notice => "started working!"
 end

 action_item :only => :index do
   session[:filtered_data] = collection.limit(nil)
   link_to('DO WORK', do_something_admin_game_stats_path)
 end
```