# ActiveAdmin Access filtered collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I'm trying to create a collection_action where I'm going to do something with the entire collection of filtered items.  My problem is that from within the collection_action I don't seem to have access to the filtered collection.  When I access `collection` it is only the items that are on the first page of records.  In my action_item I have access to `collection_before_scope` which is exactly the filtered record I want, but this is empty when I try to access it from within my `collection_action`.

Below is my `current setup` attempting to find the correct collection.

```
collection_action :dosmth, :method => :get do
  # collection_before_scope will be empty
  puts "collection_before_scope = " + collection_before_scope.to_yaml

  # collection will return only the filtered items on the front page
  puts "collection = " + collection.to_yaml

  redirect_to :back, notice: 'Something happening'
end

action_item :only => :index do
  # collection_before_scope will return the full collection that I'm looking for.
  puts "collection_before_scope = " + collection_before_scope.to_yaml 

  link_to "Export", dosmth_admin_earned_points_path(controller.params)
end
```

The closest related question I could find was this, [ActiveAdmin Collection action on filtered data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21756136/activeadmin-collection-action-on-filtered-data), which didn't seem to help me out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

**Update:**

I still have the same problem, but I have figured something out.  If I try to access the collection before the `collection_before_scope` then the correct filtered items are in collection_before_scope.  I don't want to have to access the collection just to get the correct `collection_before_scope` though.  Not sure why this would happen.

```
collection_action :dosmth, :method => :get d0
  # collection will return only the filtered items on the front page
  puts "collection = " + collection.to_yaml

  # collection_before_scope will be correct because I accessed the collection first.  why???
  puts "collection_before_scope = " + collection_before_scope.to_yaml

  redirect_to :back, notice: 'Something happening'
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

`puts "filtered collection = " + apply_filtering(collection).to_yaml` (before you call `collection`)

Why do you reach the correct filtered collection after you accessed the collection first?

The `collection` method will invoke the `find_collection` method: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/data_access.rb#L32

The `find_collection` method will invoke the `apply_filter` method: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/data_access.rb#L50

And once the `collection` method has been called:
https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/data_access.rb#L22-L27

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old, but I just ran into this issue when trying to access the filtered collection for a custom CSV download.

Because ActiveAdmin uses Ransack for search, you can grab the filtered collection using their params.

`ModelName.ransack(params[:q]).result` worked for me.