# ActiveAdmin: access to the result of filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want to display few stats on top of an ActiveAdmin index page.

Let's say I have a car model, with a color attribute and a year of fabrication. On the top of my index page, I want to display the count of red cars. But I want that count to reflect the use of filters; if I choose to show only cars built in 1995, I want the red car count to change accordingly.

How can I access the filtered list? I guessed the existence of a variable containing the result of filter action, but I can't find it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26215985/activeadmin-access-filtered-collection

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can use the variable `collection` anywhere in your index.

Something like this is working perfectly, and reflects the state of filters:

```
index do
  div "Total: #{collection.count}"
  column :attribute1
  column :attribute2
  actions
end
```

Another way is to use ransack, with this:

```
ModelName.ransack(params[:q]).result
```

But it does a useless query, call ransack again for no reason.

Inspiration found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26215985/activeadmin-access-filtered-collection).

Answer (score 0):

Use this method

```
apply_filtering(collection)
```

Inspiration found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26215985/activeadmin-access-filtered-collection)

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.